# Recorrer foreach Cabecera

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Como podría recorrer este foreach de 4 textos diferentes, pero que no me haga un cuádruple bloque y me ponga en las 4 etiquetas la misma frase, sino una frase en cada etiqueta no se si me explico un poco pero no consigo recorrer bien lo que quiero realizar y es en ese mismo foreach recorrer los 4 textos diferentes que tienen que insertarse.

```
<div class="carousel carousel-slider center tamaslider" data-indicators="true">
    <div class="carousel-fixed-item center cabezado">
        @foreach($texto as $listado1)
        <h1 class="titulo yellow-text">{{ $listado1->texto }}</h1>
        <h3 class="titulo yellow-text">{{ $listado1->texto }}</h3>
        <p class="parrafo">{{ $listado1->texto }}</p>
        <p class="parrafo">{{ $listado1->texto }}</p>
        @endforeach

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de hacerlo con un foreach puedes llamarlos directamente utilizando las claves, por ejemplo si es un array de objetos:

```
<div class="carousel carousel-slider center tamaslider" data-indicators="true">
    <div class="carousel-fixed-item center cabezado">

        <h1 class="titulo yellow-text">{{ $texto[0]->texto }}</h1>
        <h3 class="titulo yellow-text">{{ $texto[1]->texto }}</h3>
        <p class="parrafo">{{ $texto[2]->texto }}</p>
        <p class="parrafo">{{ $texto[3]->texto }}</p>

    </div>
</div>
```